# How to launch spark shell with latest version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I'm new to Spark. I have Spark 1.6.0 and Spark 2.2.0 installed on Cloudera VM.

When I hit

```
spark-submit --version
```

I get version 2.2.0, however when I launch `spark-shell`, shell gets opened in 1.6.0 version.

I even tried

```
$SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2.2.0 spark-shell
```

but it didn't worked out.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running spark2-shell. Also, check what is your SPARK_HOME in environment variables. It should point to spark 2.2 folder.

Comment: Thanks, setting up SPARK_HOME env variable worked for me.

Comment: Welcome!! Happy Coding!!